# ListBox in WPF while using ItemContainerGenerator returns null

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have listbox in my XAML, few checkbox and filter button. My application generates loads of logs which I display in the listbox.
When I have data in the listbox, what this XAML will do is user will check\uncheck checkbox. Based on that the data in the listbox will be filtered when button is clicked. Depending on data i want to show different forecolor and background color on each item.

```
private void FilterButton_Click ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
{
   //Whenever filter button is clicked, i will check for checkbox status. whichever //checkbox  is ON I will add checkbox name into Dictionary. Then I will read string from Listbox and extract particular keyword from that and match with Dictionary key. If it //matches then I will modify the background and foreground color for that particualr //listbox items. My problem here is only certain Listbox items get updated rest of them are //unchaged. When debugged i found that itemcontainergenerator returns null for all other //items. 
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ListBox1.Items.Count ; i++ )
    {

    ListBoxItem item1 = ( ListBoxItem )ListBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

        string recordType;
        string []  contentArray;

        if ( item1 == null )
            continue;
        if ( item1.Content == "" )
            continue;

        contentArray = item1.Content.ToString().Split( new char [] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
        recordType = contentArray [ 1 ];

        if ( checkBoxType.ContainsKey ( recordType ))
            {
               //int code = RecordTypeToColorCode [ recordType ];
                //item1.Foreground = ColorCodeToForeColor [ code ];
                    item1.Foreground = Brushes.DarkCyan;
                    item1.FontSize = 13;
                    item1.Background = Brushes.LightGoldenrodYellow;

            }
        else
            {
                item1.Foreground = Brushes.LightGray;
            }
    }
}
```

The issue I am seeing is that if suppose my listbox has 1000 items then only 35-40 items are updated. Rest all items are same. I debugged more into the code and I found that after some number 35-40 all items are coming as null which i why i am not able to update all items in the listbox. 
I have not turned on Virtualization in my code. Is there any way I can update all the items. Any help is appreciated. I am thinking if there is any issue with ItemCOntainerGenerator, as it only displays certain items, also Virtualization is turned off.

Comment: @HighCore Whenever filter button is clicked, i will check for checkbox status. whichever checkbox  is ON I will add checkbox name into Dictionary. Then I will read string from Listbox and extract particular keyword from that and match with Dictionary key. If it //matches then I will modify the background and foreground color for that particualr //listbox items. My problem here is only certain Listbox items get updated rest of them are unchaged. When debugged i found that itemcontainergenerator returns null for all other items.

Comment: My point still stands. You need to handle all Data at the ViewModel level and leave UI alone. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore Please see the below post I attached the screenshot. I am already having the MVVM model for the collection. But I want to filter and modfiy the template based on the content

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please look into the following diagram to more clearl;y understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it that way. Instead, you may have a boolean property in your view model item class that controls if an item is actually filtered or not (let's call it `IsFiltered`). Then you would add a DataTrigger to the `ItemContainerStyle` of your ListBox that sets all the properties that are influenced by the value of the `IsFiltered` property. Of course you would also have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that property.

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFiltered}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkCyan"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGoldenrodYellow"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListBox>
```

Now whenever the filter condition changes, you will iterate through the items collection (not the containers), and set a value for the `IsFiltered` property of each item.

Comment: My data in the listbox is dynamic. Once I receive the data, I want to find out some keywords from each Listbox item. Based on that keyword I want to apply the background and foreground color. This color may be different for each item of listBox.

Comment: Then make it an enum property instead of bool and have multiple DataTriggers.

Comment: My view model collection is of type string. Also, it comes from another project so I cannot modify it. What I have is just all messges from my collection. Whenever I click on the Filter button, it will check the state of checkboxes in my xaml. Whichever checkbox is on, it will get the name of it and search it in listboxitem content. My listboxitem will contain something like 122:343:33, ABC,  a, a,d,f. And my checkbox name will be ABC. So, if I find ABC in ListBoxitem i would like to change bckgrnd and foregrnd color. Like ABC we have like 15-20 stinrg to search for in listboxitem.